# Time Series Clustering in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have two time series- a baseline (x) and one with an event (y).  I'd like to cluster based on dissimilarity of these two time series.  Specifically, I'm hoping to create new features to predict the event.  I'm much more familiar with clustering, but fairly new to time series.

I've tried a few different things with a limited understanding...

#### Simulating data...

`x<-rnorm(100000,mean=1,sd=10)
y<-rnorm(100000,mean=1,sd=10)`

#### This package seems awesome but there is limited information available on SO or Google.

`library(TSclust)

d<-diss.ACF(x, y)`

the value of d is 

           `[,1]
[1,] 0.07173596`

I then move on to clustering...

`hc <- hclust(d)`

but I get the following error: 

`Error in if (is.na(n) || n > 65536L) stop("size cannot be NA nor exceed 65536") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

My assumption is this error is because I only have one value in d.

Alternatively, I've tried the following on a single timeseries (the event).

`library(dtw)
distMatrix <- dist(y, method="DTW")
hc <- hclust(y, method="complete")`

but it takes FOREVER to run the distance Matrix.

I have a couple of guesses at what is going wrong, but could use some guidance.

My questions...

1. Do I need a set of baseline and a set of event time series?  Or is one pairing ok to start?
2. My time series are quite large (100000 rows).  I'm guessing this is causing the SLOW distMatrix calculation.  Thoughts on this?
3. Any resources on applied clustering on large time series are welcome.  I've done a pretty thorough search, but I'm sure there are things I haven't found.
4. Is this the code you would use to accomplish these goals?

Thanks!

Comment: Time series clustering usually involves fewer observations with higher dimensions (i.e., instead of 100,000 rows of 2 columns, maybe 1000 rows of 20 columns). It's the number of rows, not columns, that increases the time to calculate a distance matrix. For low-dimension, high count clustering `kmeans` is often used.

Comment: This paper has a lot of information on TSclust package: 
[TSclust: An R Package for Time Series Clustering](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v062i01)